# BizTalk SQL Bulk Insert and Select - Best Way

Tags: sql-server, azure, biztalk

I have a requirement where I receive a CSV file which is size of 20 MB with 20000 records in it which I need to insert to a SQL Server table and need to run a stored procedure which will do some compare and give the file records which I will be sending out as an output!

My question: is bulk inserting directly into the SQL Server table advisable or should i be using a stored procedure based on the performance from BizTalk and SQL point of view ?

Please advise !

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure is just going to do a bulk insert anyway, then it shouldn't be measurably different one way or the other (assuming you truly do a bulk insert with whatever alternative framework you use to connect to and query the database with). 20,000 records (for a total of 20 MB) is a *small* amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk load directly into a staging table and then run a stored procedure.  BizTalk could orchestrate the process, but you should not flow the bulk data through the BizTalk message box.